# One source text, two outputs

Tags: conditionals, output, source

I have very long source text. 
I want to create two outputs:

1. All text
2. Only small pieces of this source text, selected by condition command

MWE (precisely: *not working*)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifPIECES
\PIECEStrue
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\lipsum[1]

\ifPIECES This is first small piece. I want this piece in two outputs. 
When PIECES is folse, I want all source text. \else\fi

\lipsum[2]

\ifPIECES This is second small piece.  \else\fi

\lipsum[3] 

\ifPIECES This is third small piece.  \else\fi

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

How I should define LaTeX command?
I am nowbe in programming, as you see.

Comment: Yes, duplicate. Thank you. But my problem stil stay not solved. : - ( Can I achiewe only PIECES, without signing all source text?

Comment: You are on the right track, however collect all the else statements in one. This will simplify the code i.e., have only one `ifPIECES else` statement.

Comment: @Yiannis, can you give same example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just collect all the `else` statements together to save on typing and errors, as shown below. Then simply you only need to change one line of the code for the false, i.e., `PIECESfalse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifPIECES
\PIECEStrue
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor}
\lipsum[1]

\ifPIECES This is small piece. I want this piece in my PDF, when PIECES is true. 
When PIECES is folse, I want all source text.

This is second small piece. I want second small piece in my PDF, when PIECES is true. When PIECES is folse, I want all source text.

 This is third small piece. I want third small piece in my PDF, when PIECES is true. 
When PIECES is folse, I want all source text.  
\else
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3] 
    \lipsum[4]
\fi

\end{document}
```

Second MWE as per comments using a command macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newif\ifPIECES
\PIECESfalse
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor}

\newcommand\twopieces[2]{%
\ifPIECES 
   #1
  \else
    #1#2
\fi
}

\twopieces{This is small piece. I want this piece in my PDF, when PIECES is true. 
   When PIECES is false, I want all source text.}{  \lipsum[2]}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Yannis, thank you. But PIECES text must be interspersed with noPIECES text. I need this for 1. version output - all text.

Comment: @Ama Will you have  a look at the second MWE, if I understood you correctly? This uses a command to save typing the text twice.

Comment: @Yannis, thank you for your tip. It works. I will use it for my purposes: -)